# Is there a way to change file details with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, file

When you right click a file, hit properties, then go to the details page, there is a lot of details on that file. Is there a way to programmatically edit these with NodeJS?

Comment: Most of the details are file type dependent. For example, for a .png file, there maybe resolution/bit depth etc.; for a .docx file, there maybe author/revision etc. I don't think there is a unified way to set these up. You may need depends on the specific packages that manipulate files of different types.